# How to create an application which uses bulk of images from web service

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, uiimageview

I am newly in iOS development.I have to make an application for a car dealer in which i have to show different cars with different colors.Please tell me the best way because i have to fetch lots of images every time from the web server.How can i reduce the rendering time in fetching the images.

Please consider i am very new in ios development and need your help.
If you have any sample application please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DB to store images as BLOB and also fetch images only when there is update at server.

Comment: Converting images to and from database BLOB format can be very processor intensive, and could cause notable lag in scrolling lists.

Comment: In that case, we can store images in Document directory and store its reference in DB.

Comment: That's a much better idea.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you send images that are no larger than needed.
If you have a list view that shows pictures of the cars, have a webservice send you premade thumbnails that are (preferably) exactly the right size.

Second, Make sure the images are loaded separately from the data set.
The best place to do this, would be in the controllers for your `UITableViewCell`.
Just have your `UITableViewCell` start their own thread to download and display the image as soon as they come into view.

Third; caching.
Make sure you save local copies of the thumbnails, and make sure the Table View Cells search for local copies of the images, and load those instead of downloading them if they are already locally present.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:-

- use lazy loading
- use paging
- use predicates for searches
- use fast enumeration

these things in general will keep your app smooth

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to show images in UITableView then you can use lazy loading. It will load images only for the displayed rows and once image for any row index has been downloaded, it will not repeat downloading for that row index. So its faster and useful.